# How do I pass multiple dictionary items into a function and return a list?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

API called is made using the variable `results`:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX', 'UNREAD']).execute()
```

A dictionary is returned:

`{'messages': [{'id': '182f01f99c14b435', 'threadId': '182ef213b5174c23'}, {'id': '182f0120c66cc135', 'threadId': '182ef214b5174c23'}], 'resultSizeEstimate': 2}`

Passing blank list and results into a function:

```
message_list = []


def return_message(message_list, results):
    messages_ = results.get('messages', [])

    for message in messages_:
        for k,v in message.items():
            message_list.append(message)
            return message_list
```

Run the function but I am only able to return 1 appended message:

```
return_message(message_list, results)
print(message_list)
```

`[{'id': '182f01f88c14b435', 'threadId': '182ef213b5154c23'}]`

How do I return the **entire** `results` passed in at the beginning from the function so it's *all* been appended onto `message_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're `return`ing right after `append`ing to your list. `return` terminates the function. So in first iteration you add one item and then the function returnes.

change it to:

```py
def return_message(message_list, results):
    messages_ = results.get("messages", [])

    for message in messages_:
        for k, v in message.items():
            message_list.append(message)
            # return message_list
    return message_list
```

Comment: thanks I got it sorted up to that point and must've been overseeing this

Answer (score 0):

```py
    for message in messages_:
        for k,v in message.items():
            message_list.append(message)
            return message_list
```

An explicit `return` statement immediately terminates a function execution and sends the return value back to the caller code. Since the `return` statement is inside the `for loop`, it terminates in the first iteration of the loop.

To get the complete list, the return statement should be outside the `for loop`
as such:

```py
    for message in messages_:
        for k,v in message.items():
            message_list.append(message)
    return message_list
```

A second point to note here is that the nested `for loop` does not really do anything here (given this is the complete code). Therefore calling the `.append()` method here, inserts the same message twice in the list.

You can solve this issue by having a conditional statement to check or by completely removing the second for loop.

#### Final Answer

```py
    for message in messages_:
        message_list.append(message)
    return message_list
```

##### Additionally,

You could simply use the `extend()` method or even concatenate the lists since bot of the variables are lists.

Using `extend()`

```py
message_list.extend(messages_)
```

Concatenating

```py
message_list += messages_
```

Both of which would give the same result.